# For a unique key ID get all other keys' values python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key

```
dictionary_name = [{'id':'123','id_2':'5676'},{'id': '123','id_2':'4545'},{'id':'123','id_2':'8375'},{'id':'156','id_2':'9374'}]
```

I need to get:

```
result = { 'id': {'123': [5676, 4545, 8375]}, {'156': [9374]} }
```

So far, I have tried the following

```
result = {}
for d in dictionary_name:
    identifier = d['id']
    if identifier not in dictionary_name:
        result[identifier] =  d['id_2']
print(result)
```

But it only outputs:
`{ '123': '8375', '156': '9374' }`

Comment: the values inside `result` should be arrays that you append each new value to. the current values in `result` is an integer, which continuously gets replaced when you see the same key.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the code now, it should work. So you say I should create a list to which I append the values?  Not sure what you mean, kbunarjo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
result = {}
for i in range(len(dictionary_name)):
    identifier = dictionary_name[i]['id']
    if identifier not in result:
        result[identifier] =  [dictionary_name[i]['id_2']]
    else:
        result[identifier].append(dictionary_name[i]['id_2'])
print(result)
```

The output would be:

```
{'123': ['5676', '4545', '8375'], '156': ['9374']}
```